# Ensuring order when calling methods that return a rx.Observable

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I call a list of methods in a loop, wherein each return an Observable & I add them to a List for processing later.

Code:

```
List<Observable> productViewObservables = new ArrayList<>();

for (ProductEnricher enricher : orchestrationStrategy.getEnrichers()) {
      productViewObservables.add(enricher.asyncEnrich(productView, productId); }
```

But Im not sure if the Observable responses get added to that list in the same order that I invoke them, which is essential for my processing. Can someone clarify this?

Comment: I feel, that storing `Observable`s in the `List` is somehow **dirty**. Isn't better to find a way how to `concat`, `merge`, `zip`, `...` them together?

Comment: Observable is monadic which means you can not only wrap a value up in it, you can also sequence it with other observables that wrap different types. There are multiple sequencing operations on the Observable type that allow you to do this in various useful ways. But it is not until you subscribe on the observable that the code is executed (it's like a thunk - or the concept of computation without actually computing anything). When the Observable sequence is executed, the operations will be performed in the order they were sequenced on the specified scheduler.

Comment: So, rather than using a list, you should do something like follows:

Comment: ```fun dummyObservable(number: Int) = Observable.fromCallable { print("hello world $number" ) } 

fun sequenceOfObservables() = dummyObservable(1).flatMap { dummyObservable(2) }

fun block() {
    sequenceOfObservables.subscribeOn(Schedulers.IO()).observeOn(Schedulers.UI()).subscribe({ }, { })```
}

Comment: And the result would be printing "Hello world 1" followed by "Hello world 2"

Comment: flatMap is one of the many sequencing operations exposed by Observable<T> class. It is frequently used to carry out simple sequence operations on an Observable stream. There are others such as map, zip, merge etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are added in the same order, because `Observable` is just a regular object. Your code is simple sequential code - you are not executing any `Observable` yet in your example, they are just objects which represent computation that might be done in the future.

If you would like to run these `Observable`s (using `subscribe` method) then you get into asynchronous world and the results might not be that obvious.

If you'd want to run your `List` of `Observable`s sequentially then you could use [`concat`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#concat-java.lang.Iterable-) method on Observable which takes Iterable as an argument